# How to remove --minUptime warning from forever.js

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, forever

I'm using forever js for starting my application, I have fired a **npm install** command on the server now forever giving warning as

***warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms***

now I don't want to set  --minUptime and --spinSleepTime and I don't want to see that warning again is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: more info at https://superuser.com/questions/1365579/how-to-remove-minuptime-warning-from-forever-js

Comment: and the contributor and maintainer not replying to my mail either